# PDO Insert Session Values to Database

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

I am working on a Session based shopping cart. I want to save the Cart items in the session to  my Database. Please I need help on how to go about it. I have read around but haven't found any clues to solving my problem. Below are 2 images, one is a sample DB table while the other is an assumed Session variables.

Using PDO, please I need help on how to insert those values into my database. Please note that the number of returned array could exceed the array count on sample image. Any offered solutions should be scalable to save as many Cart items as possible.

[image: Sample Database Table]

[image: Sample Session Variables]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about using PDO for this, compared to other SQL queries through PDO. You do however lack the prod_id value in your session array, so you probably want to add that as well.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("
    INSERT INTO
        cart
        (prod_id, code, name, qty, price, colour, size, quantity)
    VALUES
    (:prod_id, :code, :name, :qty, :price, :colour, :size, :quantity)
");

foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item)
{
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':prod_id' => $item['prod_id'],
        ':code' => $item['code'],
        ... etc ...
    ));
}
```

You can also retrieve the cart_id if needed (if it's generated by the SQL server) by calling $pdo->lastInsertId(); .. I'm guessing it already refers to a cart, so you'll need to have that available as well.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I tried implementing the code and landed at `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'`. The :bind numbers are correct and return their different values too. What could be leading to this error?

Comment: The issue may be caused by the cursor being open even from an INSERT statement, try adding $statement->closeCursor() or move the creation of $statement into the foreach loop.

Comment: It still throws the error implementing the two above suggestions. What could be prompting such? Please more help needed.

Comment: Returned to figure out my codes well after some hours I left it and all is working well. Your solution has been accepted too.